# ¿Cómo comparar Vector con una Matriz?

Tags: java, array, matrices

Tengo un vector (preguntas) con las respuestas correctas de un test (A, B, C, A, A, etc.)

Y en una matriz (matrizNotas), almacenadas las respuestas de las personas y necesito comparar los resultados guardados en la matriz en el vector de las respuestas correctas, para saber cuantos aciertos y fallos ha habido;

```html
public static void validarRespuestas (String preguntas[], String matrizNotas[][]){

        int aciertos=0, fallos=0;
        
        for (int x = 0; x < matrizNotas.length; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < matrizNotas[x].length; y++) 
            if (matrizNotas[x].equals(preguntas)){
                aciertos++;
                }
                    else {
                    fallos++;
                }    
        }
```

Comment: Aunque te cueste un poco debes investigar como se hace y luego intentarlo (esa es una parte fundamental de todo aprendizaje). Luego, cualquier problema sobre ese intento podremos ayudarte. El primer paso debes darlo tú. Saludos.

Comment: Implementa algo y nos describes los resultados y problemas que tienes... Y de paso agrega el código que estás probando para basarnos en eso para poder ayudarte.

Comment: ya esta, a ver si pueden ayudarme

Comment: @Victor ¿Cual es tu problema? ¿Cual es tu duda con el código que agregaste?

Comment: quiero comparar el valor de la primera posicion del array con la primera columna de la matriz, el segundo valor del vector, con la segunda columna de la matriz, etc...